# Server error on django app hosted using GCP

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, deployment

I got 500 Server Error on my app, which I just hosted using google cloud
https://exam-3d397.el.r.appspot.com/

I am not sure how my app.yaml should look like -

```
runtime: python39

handlers:
# This configures Google App Engine to serve the files in the app's static
# directory.
- url: /static
  static_dir: static/

# This handler routes all requests not caught above to your main app. It is
# required when static routes are defined, but can be omitted (along with
# the entire handlers section) when there are no static files defined.
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  
# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment. 
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 2
  memory_gb: 4
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

I added this to my settings.py -

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.herokuapp.com', '127.0.0.1', '.r.appspot.com']
```

There were no errors on deploying. and I have earlier deployed on heroku

My file structure looks like [structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cATIm.png)

Also I am able to view my static files by going to https://exam-3d397.el.r.appspot.com/static/images/logo.png

I am a beginner to hosting with google cloud, any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the details of the 500 Error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see the mixed app.yaml Elements, from the App Engine Standard and Flexible environments. Remove the "resources" Element, as it seems you are trying to use the standard environment and try.

Also, give the ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"], if the above still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

- From the app.yaml file provided by you it seems you are mixing the configuration for standard and flexible environments.
- Please make sure which environment to use and refer to [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) for standard configuration and [this document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/reference/app-yaml) for flexible configuration.
- Also from the handlers section in the app.yaml configuration it seems like there is some error with the URI path. Please follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref#handlers_element) to know how to give the correct path in handlers.